# Optimising multi-dimensional functions with Ceres

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, multidimensional-array, ceres-solver

I want to use Ceres to optimise a function of n parameters. How to find the gradient of this function is unclear, although I do have a well defined cost. I have been using GSL so far, with numeric differentiation, but I thought I would try to use Ceres with automatic diff.

I have had a look at the toy example [helloworld_analytic_diff.cc](https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/1.11.0rc1/examples/helloworld_analytic_diff.cc) in which they use AutoDiff to minimise the function f(x) = 0.5 (10 - x)^2 and read the tutorial, so I thought I would try and extend this to the two dimensional function f(x,y) = (10-x)^2 +(20- y)^2, which has a global minimum at x, y = 10, 20. But I am getting a little stuck on this:

```
#include "ceres/ceres.h"
#include "glog/logging.h"

using ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction;
using ceres::CostFunction;
using ceres::Problem;
using ceres::Solver;
using ceres::Solve;


struct CostFunctor {
  template <typename T> bool operator()(const T* const x, T* residual) const {
      const T x1 = x[0];
      const T y1 = x[1];
      residual[0] = (10.0-x[0]) + (20.0-x[1]);

    return true;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

    double x[2] = {0.5, -3.0};
    const double initial_x[2] = {0.5, -3.0};
    Problem problem;

    CostFunction* cost_function = new AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, 1, 2>(new CostFunctor);
          problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function, NULL, &x[0]);

    // Run the solver!
    Solver::Options options;
    options.minimizer_progress_to_stdout = true;
    Solver::Summary summary;
    Solve(options, &problem, &summary);

    std::cout << summary.BriefReport() << "\n";
    std::cout << "x : " << initial_x[0] << ", " << initial_x[0]
        << " -> " << x[0] << ", " << x[1]<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If I run this however, it winds up converging to something incorrect, depending on the initial guess:

```
Ceres Solver Report: Iterations: 3, Initial cost: 5.281250e+02, Final cost: 3.667046e-16, Termination: CONVERGENCE
x : 0.5, 0.5 -> 16.75, 13.25
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong here?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your cost functor is wrong.
the optimization problem you are solving is

[(10.0-x) + (20.0-y)]^2

and not

(10-x)^2 +(20- y)^2,

what you should do here is to have two cost functors, something like as follows:

```
struct CostFunctor1 {
  template <typename T> bool operator()(const T* const x, T* residual) const {
      residual[0] = 10.0-x[0];
      return true;
  }
};

struct CostFunctor2 {
  template <typename T> bool operator()(const T* const x, T* residual) const {
      residual[0] = 20.0-x[1];
      return true;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

    double x[2] = {0.5, -3.0};
    const double initial_x[2] = {0.5, -3.0};
    Problem problem;
    problem.AddResidualBlock(new AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor1, 1, 2>(new 
    CostFunctor1), NULL, &x[0]);
    problem.AddResidualBlock(new AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor2, 1, 2>(new 
    CostFunctor2), NULL, &x[0]);

    // Run the solver!
    Solver::Options options;
    options.minimizer_progress_to_stdout = true;
    Solver::Summary summary;
    Solve(options, &problem, &summary);

    std::cout << summary.BriefReport() << "\n";
    std::cout << "x : " << initial_x[0] << ", " << initial_x[0]
        << " -> " << x[0] << ", " << x[1]<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```